# Select values which exist before and after a certain time period

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following simple table which you can also find in the `SQL Fiddle` [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/833d32/5):

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    Customer TEXT,
    Order_Date DATE

);

INSERT INTO Orders
(Customer, Order_Date)
VALUES 
("Customer A", "2017-05-23"),
("Customer B", "2018-09-10"),
("Customer B", "2018-12-14"),
("Customer A", "2019-01-03"),
("Customer A", "2019-02-15"),
("Customer C", "2017-09-04"),
("Customer B", "2019-01-09"),
("Customer A", "2019-02-16"),
("Customer C", "2019-02-12"),
("Customer B", "2018-01-03");
```

As you can see the table displays the order dates from different customers. 
I use the below SQL to get the all customers that placed an order in February 2019:

```
SELECT Customer
FROM ORDERS
WHERE Order_Date >= "2019-02-01 00:00:00"
AND Order_Date < "2019-03-01 00:00:00"
```

All this works fine so far.

---

However, now I want to achieve that only customers are listed which

a) placed an order **in February** and

```
WHERE order in >= "2019-02-01 00:00:00" AND < "2018-03-01 00:00:00"
```

b) **did not** place an order in the **12 month before** and

```
WHERE no order < "2019-02-01 00:00:00" AND >= "2018-01-02 00:00:00"
```

c) placed an order **before this 12 month period**

```
WHERE order in < "2018-01-02 00:00:00"
```

What do I need to change in my query to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bit complicated, but you can use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT o.Customer
FROM ORDERS o
GROUP BY o.Customer
HAVING SUM( o.Order_Date >= '2019-02-01' AND o.Order_Date < '2019-03-01' ) > 0 AND
       SUM( o.Order_Date >= '2018-01-02' AND o.Order_Date < '2019-02-01' ) = 0 AND
       SUM( o.Order_Date < '2018-01-02' ) > 0 ;
```

Comment: Perfect. Exaclty what I needed. Do you also have an idea for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872354/count-values-which-exist-before-and-after-a-certain-time-period