# Count values which exist before and after a certain time period

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following simple table which you can also find in the `SQL Fiddle` [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74d8fb/3):

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    Customer TEXT,
    Order_Date DATE
);

INSERT INTO Orders
(Customer, Order_Date)
VALUES 
("Customer A", "2017-05-23"),
("Customer B", "2018-09-10"),
("Customer B", "2018-12-14"),
("Customer A", "2019-01-03"),
("Customer A", "2019-02-15"),
("Customer C", "2017-09-04"),
("Customer B", "2019-01-09"),
("Customer A", "2019-02-16"),
("Customer C", "2019-02-12"),
("Customer C", "2019-02-15"),
("Customer B", "2018-01-03");
```

As you can see the table displays the order dates from different customers. 
 
I use the below SQL to get the customers that

```
a) placed an order in February 2019 and
b) did not place an order in the 12 month before and
c) placed an order before this 12 months period
```

Referring to the answer in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872070/select-values-which-exist-before-and-after-a-certain-time-period) .

```
SELECT o.Customer
FROM ORDERS o
GROUP BY o.Customer
HAVING SUM( o.Order_Date >= '2019-02-01' AND o.Order_Date < '2019-03-01' ) > 0 AND
       SUM( o.Order_Date >= '2018-01-02' AND o.Order_Date < '2019-02-01' ) = 0 AND
       SUM( o.Order_Date < '2018-01-02' ) > 0 ;
```

All this works fine so far.

---

However, now I want to achieve that the SQL is both listing the customers which meet the above criterias but also `counts` the numbers of orders which the customer placed in `February 2019`:

In the example above I would expect the following result:

```
Customer C     2
```

What do I need to change in my query to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add that to the `select`:

```
SELECT o.Customer,
       SUM( o.Order_Date >= '2019-02-01' AND o.Order_Date < '2019-03-01' ) as num_feb_orders
FROM ORDERS o
GROUP BY o.Customer
HAVING SUM( o.Order_Date >= '2019-02-01' AND o.Order_Date < '2019-03-01' ) > 0 AND
       SUM( o.Order_Date >= '2018-01-02' AND o.Order_Date < '2019-02-01' ) = 0 AND
       SUM( o.Order_Date < '2018-01-02' ) > 0 ;
```

Comment: Is there also a way to make it unique so if the cusomter orders 2 times in February as in the example above it only displays 1 instead of 2?

Comment: @Michi . . . You can use `max()` . . . but you already know that the customer ordered in February because that is one of your filtering conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the additional help. Answer with max() http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/938007/1