# Create list of dates if values exist before and after a certain time period

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table which you can also find in the `SQL Fiddle` [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5dc67f/1):

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    Customer TEXT,
    Order_Date DATE
);

INSERT INTO Orders
(Customer, Order_Date)
VALUES 
("Customer A", "2017-05-23"),
("Customer A", "2019-01-03"),
("Customer A", "2019-02-15"),
("Customer A", "2019-02-16"),

("Customer B", "2018-09-10"),
("Customer B", "2019-01-09"),

("Customer C", "2016-09-04"),
("Customer C", "2019-02-12"),
("Customer C", "2019-02-20"),

("Customer D", "2017-03-15"),
("Customer D", "2019-02-17"),
("Customer D", "2019-02-19"),
("Customer D", "2019-02-20"),

("Customer E", "2019-02-03"),
("Customer E", "2015-10-12");
```

As you can see the table displays the order dates from different customers. 
I use the below SQL to get the `unique count of orders` for customers that:

```
a) placed an order in February 2019 and
b) did not place an order in the 12 month before and
c) placed an order before this 12 months period
```

Referring to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872354/count-values-which-exist-before-and-after-a-certain-time-period/54872379?noredirect=1#comment96515150_54872379).

```
SELECT o.Customer,
       MAX( o.Order_Date >= '2019-02-01' AND o.Order_Date < '2019-03-01' ) as num_feb_orders
FROM ORDERS o
GROUP BY o.Customer
HAVING SUM( o.Order_Date >= '2019-02-01' AND o.Order_Date < '2019-03-01' ) > 0 AND
       SUM( o.Order_Date >= '2018-02-01' AND o.Order_Date < '2019-02-01' ) = 0 AND
       SUM( o.Order_Date < '2018-02-01' ) > 0 ;
```

All this works fine so far.

---

However, now instead of make the `GROUP BY` based on the customer I want to make the `GROUP BY` based on the `Order_Date` so all `latest order_dates in February` referring to customers that fullfill the above criterias should be listed. The result should look like this.

```
Order_Date      UniqueOrders
2019-02-03            1       --> Customer E
2019-02-20            2       --> Customer C and Customer D
```

What do I need to change in my code to make this work?

Comment: A wild guess... `Select order_date, count(customer) uo from ( your query here ) x group by order_date`

Comment: So all calculation is relative to latest order date?

Comment: Yeah, so if the customer ordered mutliple times in February (for example customer D in the above example) I only want to list the latest order date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a subquery:

```
SELECT last_feb_order_date, COUNT(*) as num_customers
FROM (SELECT o.Customer,
             MAX( o.Order_Date >= '2019-02-01' AND o.Order_Date < '2019-03-01' ) as num_feb_orders,
             MAX(CASE WHEN o.Order_Date >= '2019-02-01' AND o.Order_Date < '2019-03-01' THEN o.Order_Date END) as last_feb_order_date
      FROM ORDERS o
      GROUP BY o.Customer
      HAVING SUM( o.Order_Date >= '2019-02-01' AND o.Order_Date < '2019-03-01' ) > 0 AND
             SUM( o.Order_Date >= '2018-02-01' AND o.Order_Date < '2019-02-01' ) = 0 AND
             SUM( o.Order_Date < '2018-02-01' ) > 0
     ) oc
GROUP BY last_feb_order_date
ORDER BY last_feb_order_date;
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps I have used the given query as a sub query to get the required out put,

```
SELECT OrderDate, 
    (COUNT(*) 
     FROM (
         SELECT o.Customer, MAX(o.Order_Date) AS OrderDate,
             MAX( o.Order_Date >= '2019-02-01' AND o.Order_Date < '2019-03-01' ) AS UniqueOrders
         FROM ORDERS AS o
         GROUP BY o.Customer
        HAVING SUM( o.Order_Date >= '2019-02-01' AND o.Order_Date < '2019-03-01' ) > 0 AND
           SUM( o.Order_Date >= '2018-02-01' AND o.Order_Date < '2019-02-01' ) = 0 AND
           SUM( o.Order_Date < '2018-02-01' ) > 0)a
GROUP BY OrderDate ;
```